# GraphQL query to get status from a new github project for an issue

Tags: github, graphql, github-issues, github-projects

With classic github projects I used to get the status of the issue along with other issue information using a single request:

```
{
  search(query: "is:open is:issue assignee:@me archived:false", type: ISSUE, first: 30) {
    issueCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Issue {
          number
          title
          url
          ...
          projectCards(first: 2) {
            nodes {
              column {
                 name     <--- This would be a status of the issue in project
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But with new github projects, I cannot figure out how to get this information.
The closest I could get is the following, but it returns statuses of all the issues in the linked project:

```
...
projectsV2(first: 10, query: "") {
  nodes {
    items(first: 10) {
      nodes {
        fieldValueByName(name: "Status") {
          ... on ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

I guess I can get issue status in a separate request - query Project by issue id, but I would like to use one request, which would return information about the issue, as well as status from all linked projects.